# Eager Loading using UserManager with EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Currently have `ApplicationUser` class with some custom properties, like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Content> Content { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to get the current logged user with the list of related data (`Content` property).

In my controller, if I put:

```
Applicationuser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

I get the logged user, but without any related data.
But, if I retrieve the current user using the `ApplicationDbContext`, like below, I can retrieve the related data:

```
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
ApplicationUser userWithContent = _context.Users.Include(c => c.Content).Where(u => u.Id == user.Id).ToList();
```

But this doesn't appear correctly for me!

Any idea?

Comment: Use `var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User)` instead, that is not querying database, and then do the eager loading.

Answer (score 3):

checking the source code of `[UserManager][1]`, GetUserAsync will end up calling `FindByIdAsync`, which will be provided by an `IUserStore` implementation. Looking the source code in the question, very likely using EFCore as the IUserStore implementation.

In case of EFCore, it was mention [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6935#issuecomment-258520295) that `Find` cannot be combined with `include`, so I guest what've you done to do eager loading in your question, may actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you need those properties in every request, there's a better way to get them without query the database in each request.

You can store those properties as `Claims` by writing your own `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>` and reading them from `HttpContext.User`

```
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {

    }

    protected async override Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Name", user.Name));

        for (int i = 0; i < user.Content.Count; i++)
        {
            string content = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.Content[i]);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Content", content));
        }

        return identity;
    }
}
```

Also you need to register it to service collection

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

You can access these properties with this code

```
string name = httpContext.User.FindFirstValue("Name");

List<Content> contents = new List<Content>();
foreach (Claim claim in httpContext.User.FindAll("Content"))
{
    Content content = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Content>(claim.Value);
    contents.Add(content);
};
```